# Magento applying tax twice

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Magento 1.9.0.1 is calculating tax twice for products.
I've set 2 tax zones for 3 tax types:

1. India > Karnataka > 4% (called VAT)
2. India > * > 4% (called CST)
3. [none] -- For all countries except India

Problem appears when I select India > Karnataka and estimate price. Both CST (matching all states) and VAT (matching only Karnataka) get calculated and added up resulting in 8% 
e.g.,

`product value 10$
      VAT(4%)  0.4$
      CST(4%)  0.4$
Grand total   10.8$`

For both the tax rules, priority is `0` and "calculate tax on subtotal" is `off`

I think "India > Karnataka" shipping location is matching both the tax rules hence tax is getting doubled. Is there a way I can specify "All states except Karnataka" ?

PS: I'm using two different tax rates for `*` and `karnataka` as these rates may be different in future even if they are same as of now.

Comment: Why don't you add a tax zone for all states ?

Answer (score 1):

To add cst and vat in 1 rule i.e. if you want that :
1. cst for all other states of india
2. vat for your origin state eg. Karnataka

Then do as told below:

1. In Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Zones & Rates, add 2  taxes 1 with name : cst and 1 with name: vat. Select the state as * for CST and state as Karnataka for VAT. Set same priority for both the tax rates for eg. priority : 0.
2. Then in Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Rules. Create a rule and select both CST and VAT in that rule and save the rule.

Magento will automatically apply any 1 of CST or VAT according to the state specified in the address (as per tax configuration setting for applying tax based on either of: shipping origin/shipping address/billing address)

[click here to see image to set tax rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDAjW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
There are 36 states (counting UTs as states) so its not practical to add all of them.

Under tax rules, instead of having two rules, I selected both CST and VAT tax rates in a single rule and it worked.